# Simplifying an 8-bit boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am asked to find a minimum SOP implementation of a Hex to Braille code converter. Assuming my truth table is accurate, and D stands for "Don't Care", an 8-bit K-map seems impractical. Are there any other tools for hand analysis other than basic boolean algebra simplification?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools like [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/) or [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) are able to minimize a truth-table with multiple outputs and don't cares.

With [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/), your truth-table looks as follows:

[image]

It is possible to minimize the number of product terms in different ways:

[image]

The result is one minimized sum-of-products expression per output:

[image]

You can turn this into a multi-level circuit of Boolean gates:

[image]

In case you want to experiment with Karnaugh maps including don't cares, the following web application is helpful:

[Karnaugh-Veitch Map](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/), Marburg University

Note that a four-bit map is sufficient. You need one map per output.